# what can I do with a typedef to a class non-static member method

Tags: c++

I just read [cppFaq](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/pointers-to-members#typedef-for-ptr-to-memfn).  And copy/modify/run the following code.

```
#include <iostream>

class Fred {
    public:
        Fred(): a_(0) {}
        Fred(int a): a_(a) {}
        int f() { return a_;}
        int g() { return 2;}
        int h() { return 3;}
    private:
        int a_;
};


typedef int (Fred::*FredMemFn)();

int main() {
    FredMemFn p = &Fred::f;
    std::cout << p() << std::endl;  // this line added by me, and I know it doesn't work
    return 0;
}
```

In this case, what can I do with the "p"?

Comment: Read the next entry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you mean, how do you use the pointer to call the member function, then you'll need an object to call it on:

```
Fred fred(42);
std::cout << (fred.*p)() << std::endl;  // prints 42
```

There's also an `->*` operator to call it via a pointer to `Fred`.